# When is $\cos\frac{\pi}{x}<0$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

This seems really simple, but I'm trying to find a way to solve $\cos\frac{\pi}{x}<0$. I get $$x\geq \frac{\pi}{\arccos0}=\frac{\pi}{(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{2}{2k+1}$$

for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But this can't be it, $\cos\frac{\pi}{x}$ varies from positive to negative on the interval [-2,2].  So what from here? The answer should be $\frac{2}{4k+3}<x<\frac{2}{4k+1}$, but I have no idea how to get there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start it over:

For an angle $\alpha\in [0,2\pi)$, we have that $\cos(\alpha)<0$ if and only if $\alpha\in (\pi/2,\ 3\pi/2)$. Altogether, for arbitrary $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, it means that $2k\pi+\pi/2\ <\ \alpha\ <\ 2k\pi+3\pi/2\ $ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Now substitue $\alpha=\displaystyle\frac\pi x\,$.